# How to add column for every month and generate number i.e. 1,2,3..etc

Tags: python, pandas, loops

I have a huge csv file of dataframe. However, I don't have the date column. I only have the sales for every month from Jan-2022 until Dec-2034. Below is the example of my dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 
    
data = [[6661, 'Mobile Phone', 43578, 5000, 78564, 52353, 67456, 86965, 43634, 32546, 56332, 58944, 98878, 68588, 43634, 3463, 74533, 73733, 64436, 45426, 57333, 89762, 4373, 75457, 74845, 86843, 59957, 74563, 745335, 46342, 463473, 52352, 23622], 
        [6672, 'Play Station', 4475, 2546, 5757, 2352, 57896, 98574, 53536, 56533, 88645, 44884, 76585, 43575, 74573, 75347, 57573, 5736, 53737, 35235, 5322, 54757, 74573, 75473, 77362, 21554, 73462, 74736, 1435, 4367, 63462, 32362, 56332],
        [6631, 'Laptop', 35347, 36376, 164577, 94584, 78675, 76758, 75464, 56373, 56343, 54787, 7658, 76584, 47347, 5748, 8684, 75373, 57573, 26626, 25632, 73774, 847373, 736646, 847457, 57346, 43732, 347346, 75373, 6473, 85674, 35743, 45734], 
        [6600, 'Camera', 14365, 60785, 25436, 46747, 75456, 97644, 63573, 56433, 25646, 32548, 14325, 64748, 68458, 46537, 7537, 46266, 7457, 78235, 46223, 8747, 67453, 4636, 3425, 4636, 352236, 6622, 64625, 36346, 46346, 35225, 6436],
        [6643, 'Lamp', 324355, 143255, 696954, 97823, 43657, 66686, 56346, 57563, 65734, 64484, 87685, 54748, 9868, 573, 73472, 5735, 73422, 86352, 5325, 84333, 7473, 35252, 7547, 73733, 7374, 32266, 654747, 85743, 57333, 46346, 46266]]

ds = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['ID', 'Product', 'SalesJan-22', 'SalesFeb-22', 'SalesMar-22', 'SalesApr-22', 'SalesMay-22', 'SalesJun-22', 'SalesJul-22', 'SalesAug-22', 'SalesSep-22', 'SalesOct-22', 'SalesNov-22', 'SalesDec-22', 'SalesJan-23', 'SalesFeb-23', 'SalesMar-23', 'SalesApr-23', 'SalesMay-23', 'SalesJun-23', 'SalesJul-23', 'SalesAug-23', 'SalesSep-23', 'SalesOct-23', 'SalesNov-23', 'SalesDec-23', 'SalesJan-24', 'SalesFeb-24', 'SalesMar-24', 'SalesApr-24', 'SalesMay-24',  'SalesJun-24', 'SalesJul-24']
```

[image]

Since I have more than 10 monthly sales column, I want to loop the date after each of the month sales column. Then, the first 6 months will generate number 1, while the next 12 months will generate number 2, then another 12 months will generate number 3, another subsequent 12 months will generate number 4 and so on.

Below shows the sample of result that I want:

[image]

Is there any way to perform the loop and adding the date column beside each of the sales month?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a vectorial approach (using `insert` repeatedly is inefficient):

```
# convert (valid) columns to datetime
cols = pd.to_datetime(ds.columns, format='Sales%b-%y', errors='coerce')
# identify valid dates
m = cols.notna()
# get year
y = cols[m].year
# calculate number (1 for first 6 months, then +1 per 12 months)
num = ((cols[m].month+12*(y-y.min()))+5)//12+1

# slice dates columns, assign the number, rename
df2 = (ds.loc[:, m].assign(**dict(zip(ds.columns[m], num)))
         .rename(columns=lambda x: x[5:])
       )

# get new order of columns
idx = np.r_[np.zeros((~m).sum()), np.tile(np.arange(m.sum()), 2)+1]
# concat and reorder
out = pd.concat([ds, df2], axis=1).iloc[:, np.argsort(idx)]

print(out)
```

output:

```
     ID       Product  SalesJan-22  Jan-22  SalesFeb-22  Feb-22  SalesMar-22  Mar-22  SalesApr-22  Apr-22  SalesMay-22  May-22  SalesJun-22  Jun-22  SalesJul-22  Jul-22  SalesAug-22  Aug-22  Sep-22  SalesSep-22  Oct-22  SalesOct-22  SalesNov-22  Nov-22  Dec-22  SalesDec-22  Jan-23  SalesJan-23  Feb-23  SalesFeb-23  SalesMar-23  Mar-23  Apr-23  SalesApr-23  SalesMay-23  May-23  SalesJun-23  Jun-23  Jul-23  SalesJul-23  SalesAug-23  Aug-23  Sep-23  SalesSep-23  SalesOct-23  Oct-23  Nov-23  SalesNov-23  Dec-23  SalesDec-23  Jan-24  SalesJan-24  Feb-24  SalesFeb-24  Mar-24  SalesMar-24  Apr-24  SalesApr-24  May-24  SalesMay-24  SalesJun-24  Jun-24  SalesJul-24  Jul-24
0  6661  Mobile Phone        43578       1         5000       1        78564       1        52353       1        67456       1        86965       1        43634       2        32546       2       2        56332       2        58944        98878       2       2        68588       2        43634       2         3463        74533       2       2        73733        64436       2        45426       2       3        57333        89762       3       3         4373        75457       3       3        74845       3        86843       3        59957       3        74563       3       745335       3        46342       3       463473        52352       3        23622       4
1  6672  Play Station         4475       1         2546       1         5757       1         2352       1        57896       1        98574       1        53536       2        56533       2       2        88645       2        44884        76585       2       2        43575       2        74573       2        75347        57573       2       2         5736        53737       2        35235       2       3         5322        54757       3       3        74573        75473       3       3        77362       3        21554       3        73462       3        74736       3         1435       3         4367       3        63462        32362       3        56332       4
2  6631        Laptop        35347       1        36376       1       164577       1        94584       1        78675       1        76758       1        75464       2        56373       2       2        56343       2        54787         7658       2       2        76584       2        47347       2         5748         8684       2       2        75373        57573       2        26626       2       3        25632        73774       3       3       847373       736646       3       3       847457       3        57346       3        43732       3       347346       3        75373       3         6473       3        85674        35743       3        45734       4
3  6600        Camera        14365       1        60785       1        25436       1        46747       1        75456       1        97644       1        63573       2        56433       2       2        25646       2        32548        14325       2       2        64748       2        68458       2        46537         7537       2       2        46266         7457       2        78235       2       3        46223         8747       3       3        67453         4636       3       3         3425       3         4636       3       352236       3         6622       3        64625       3        36346       3        46346        35225       3         6436       4
4  6643          Lamp       324355       1       143255       1       696954       1        97823       1        43657       1        66686       1        56346       2        57563       2       2        65734       2        64484        87685       2       2        54748       2         9868       2          573        73472       2       2         5735        73422       2        86352       2       3         5325        84333       3       3         7473        35252       3       3         7547       3        73733       3         7374       3        32266       3       654747       3        85743       3        57333        46346       3        46266       4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest approach I can think of:

```py
for i, col in enumerate(ds.columns[2:]):
    ds.insert(2 * i + 2, col.removeprefix("Sales"), (i - 6) // 12 + 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little solution : (I put the year unstead of your 1, 2, ... incrementation since i thought it is more representative, but you can change it easily)

```
idx_counter = 0
for idx, col in enumerate(ds.columns):
    
    if col.startswith('Sales'):
        date = col.replace('Sales', '')
        year = col.split('-')[1]
        ds.insert(loc=idx + 1 + idx_counter, column=date, value=[year] * ds.shape[0])
        idx_counter += 1
```

output:

```
     ID       Product  SalesJan-22 Jan-22  SalesFeb-22 Feb-22  SalesMar-22 Mar-22  SalesApr-22 Apr-22  ...  SalesMar-24 Mar-24  SalesApr-24 Apr-24  SalesMay-24 May-24  SalesJun-24 Jun-24  SalesJul-24 Jul-24
0  6661  Mobile Phone        43578     22         5000     22        78564     22        52353     22  ...       745335     24        46342     24       463473     24        52352     24        23622     24
1  6672  Play Station         4475     22         2546     22         5757     22         2352     22  ...         1435     24         4367     24        63462     24        32362     24        56332     24
2  6631        Laptop        35347     22        36376     22       164577     22        94584     22  ...        75373     24         6473     24        85674     24        35743     24        45734     24
3  6600        Camera        14365     22        60785     22        25436     22        46747     22  ...        64625     24        36346     24        46346     24        35225     24         6436     24
4  6643          Lamp       324355     22       143255     22       696954     22        97823     22  ...       654747     24        85743     24        57333     24        46346     24        46266     24
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick.

```
import math
new_cols = []
old_cols = [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('Sales')]
for i, col in enumerate(old_cols):
    new_cols.append(col[5:])
    if i < 6:
        val = 1
    else:
        val = ((i+6)/12)+1
    df[col[5:]] = math.floor(val)
    
df[['ID', 'Product'] + [x for y in zip(old_cols, new_cols) for x in y]]
```